# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/arpit/.steampath'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ubuntu, npm

I get [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/arpit/.steampath'] error when I try to run `npm start`. I have tried removing node modules and Re-installing them, I have also reinstalled NPM but this error is not going away. I am in the right location in my terminal. I am using Linux operating system.
the full error is

```
Compiling...
/home/arpit/Desktop/Coding/API-Practice/frontend/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/arpit/.steampath'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '/home/arpit/.steampath'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to redirect the *npm* output to see the actual error:

```
npm run start 2>&1 | tee /tmp/output
```

Seems to be a bug on `facebook/creat-react-app`. Check also [this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9825#issuecomment-925091285) and [this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9156#) issue.

Comment: Thank you save me lots of time.